# onpageshow only working correctly in webkit (runs function only when visible onscreen)

Tags: javascript, html, events, webkit, visible

i am adding a html file via a object tag. The div that surrounds the object tag is hidden (display:none).

The problem I am having is that I have put a onpageshow event on body tag of the html object but it is functioning differently across the browsers.

- Firefox seems to play the function as soon as the html is loaded within the object
- Webkit (Safari/Chrome) plays it only when i unhide the div (which is what i want)
- Opera / IE10 doesn't play the function at all.

Is there another way to get make a function run only when it is visible onscreen?

Here is a demo. of what I am trying to do.

Code for main window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function runthis()
    {
        if ( document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display == "none" )
        {

            document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById("hide").innerHTML = 'Div showing';

        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("hide").innerHTML = 'Div hidden';
        }           
    }

    function removeObject()
    {
        if( document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML == '' )
        {
            document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = '<object id="test_object" name="name" data="frame.html" onshow="callme();"></object>';
            document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = 'Object added';
        }
        else
        {           
            document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = 'Object removed';
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="display:none"></div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="runthis();">Show/Hide</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="removeObject();">Add/Remove</button>
        <div id="status"><span>Status: </span><span id="hide">Div hidden</span> | <span id="add">Object removed</span></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Code for included object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callme()
    {
        alert("running");
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onpageshow="callme();">
</body>
```

So basically the alert should run only when the div is showing and the object has loaded.

Comment: Please include the code, it makes the question easier to answer.

Comment: sure, I have included it into the original post. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Went with a different route and used postMessage instead.